# the class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the StoryBoard I have one scene contains some TextFields, buttons and  a UITableView. an instance of the UITableView is declared in the header file, but when I tried to access the method 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' I receive the following error

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.
```

I googled that error, and some results suggested that it is about linking the DataSource and Delegate properties to the ViewController, but I still receive the same error

please let me know how to fix this error.

**code-1**:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");
   NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellId";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1    
   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
   forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }

   //[cell.textLabel setText: [dataArray 
   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

  if (textFieldRowNameAsString != nil)
    cell.textLabel.text = textFieldRowNameAsString;

 return cell;

 }
```

**code-2**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,   
UITableViewDataSource>
{
NSString *textFieldRowNameAsString;
UITableView *tableView1;
UITableViewCell *prototypeCell;
UIView *contentView;

}
```

**image-1**:

[image]

Comment: What is the reason you want to "access the method 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'" ? That is not what you normally need to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the error if you

**use always the passed `tableView` instance in all table view data source and delegate methods**.

And you don't need to check the cell for `nil` because this `dequeueReusable` method returns always a valid cell.

Since cells are reused it's highly recommended to set all UI elements always to a defined state.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellId";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

      if (textFieldRowNameAsString != nil) {
         cell.textLabel.text = textFieldRowNameAsString;
      } else {
         cell.textLabel.text = ""
      }

     return cell;
 }
```

PS: If you want to have a custom table view variable / property you have to create an `IBOutlet` and connect the table view to it. A simple property is not sufficient.

Comment: thanks..would you please check the picture i posted above in the ...please have a lot at the section on the right, in the "referencing outlets" there is

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps : This may resolve your problem.

Delete the connection for tableView1 in the storyboard and reconnect to the right variable name and try. Double check identifier string text. It should match exactly same.

Comment: thanks. the uitableView object i have is called tableView1..and when i checked the the connection between the view controller and tableView to set the the dataSource and the delegate , i found it is called tableView "i mean the referencing outlet" as shown in the picture posted in the update section above..is there any way to change the the name from tableView to tableView1

Comment: Yes you can change. First delete existing connection to tableView and then connect tableView1 to tableView in storyboard. This way you can change name from tableView to tableView1.

Answer (score 1):

Just be sure to check "Inherit Module From target" from Storyboard after selection your View component.

[image]